# Cant connect Client-Server with Websockets

Tags: c#, http, websocket, tcpclient, tcplistener

Im create simple web server on C# .Net Framework with Tcp-Listner Tcp-Client connections.

Now im trying to do support of Websocket connection for chat\or something else.

For sockets im use GenericHandler and js for connect them. After getting request from client

```
GET /socket/SocketHandler.ashx HTTP/1.1
Host: ***************
Connection: Upgrade
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36
Upgrade: websocket
Origin: http://************
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Sec-WebSocket-Key: aroK0T3g3A6oSxC6Qz1QDg==
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
```

im sending response to client from server with concatenate key **aroK0T3g3A6oSxC6Qz1QDg==** with GUID,  hash it SHA1 and convert in Base64 format for getting accept key **zGccDw/PeOtlWAmdPT6HBtyywYc=**

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: zGccDw/PeOtlWAmdPT6HBtyywYc=
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: chat
```

but after this, client (browser) says

> failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Incorrect
> 'Sec-WebSocket-Accept' header value

So, what im do wrong and how to fix that?

upd: for example, im use this code for conversion

```
string ClientKey = socketKey;
            string GUID = "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11";
            var conc = ClientKey + GUID;
            var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(conc);
            var hash1 = SHA1.Create().ComputeHash(buffer);
            var AcceptKey = System.Convert.ToBase64String(hash1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also my own WebSocket client in C#. And It had been tested and working with ASP.NET Core.

Then, I've tested your secure key, the result is different. I got below hash.

```
QCd+628gwEVYxyYQ8ekJny8ZHCo=
```

Comment: hmm, i think problem with regex matching of key from request, il try to fix that, thx for response

Comment: after testing of regex, im find intersting bug 

`Console.WriteLine($@"{match.Value}!");` 

im use for debuging this case, for looking of ending string 

what im expect 

'Sec-WebSocket-Key: uSzZ8HRsSjd3XyfoPogD+w==!`

and what im get 

`!ec-WebSocket-Key: uSzZ8HRsSjd3XyfoPogD+w==`

Comment: @NikolayB. Try reading line by line and split by ':' and trimming them. It is much easier and fit. For example, the HTTP header keys are case insensitive but the hash must treated as case sensitive. Also, the ':' and key can trail more than one spaces even '\t'. It is hard to express with Regex.

Comment: im adding Trim() into end of match.value, and now all works perfect with keys. But now im getting new trouble. `A server must not mask any frames that it sends to the client.`

Comment: @NikolayB. Take a look the spec document more carefully. I cannot remember the section, but as I know, the client must use mask and server must not use mask.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I will go to study the issue deeper, this problem is closed.